# How to NSLog ASCII infinite symbol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have

```
NSLog(@"%c", (char) 236);
```

trying to print the infinite symbol defined in ASCII. But that doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming it doesn't have to be a C `char` you could use the UTF encoding of the infinity symbol in an `NSString`:

```
NSLog(@"%@", @"\u221E");
```

Answer (score 8):

ASCII characters range from 0 to 127, there is no ASCII character 236. If you want the [infinity symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm), you can use `NSString`:

```
NSString *infinity = @"\u221E";
NSLog(@"%@", infinity);
```

You can also put it inside a `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t infinity = L'\u221E';
NSLog(@"%lc", infinity); // %lc means wide character
```